# Pygame - How do I stop a sprite from leaving the edge of the window?

Tags: python, pygame

I have my window popping up and I can move my sprite around the screen with my arrow keys.  I know there's a collision function with sprite on sprite collision, but I can't seem to figure out how to stop them from moving outside of the visible area.  Any thoughts?

my move function:

```
def moveme(self,coords)
    #coords=(x,y)
    self.rect.move_ip(coords)
```

for the event handler i'm using something like

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    character.moveme((0, -4))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

How about using clamp_ip after moving?

```
Rect.clamp_ip(Rect): return None
```

It takes a Rectangle which in your case is your window tuple.

So your code would look like this:

```
screen_rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (700, 400))

def moveme(self,x,y):
    self.rect.move_ip((x,y))
    self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to upvote yet, but this was great.  I didn't know about clamp_ip.  I already had self.area defined with a pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself after looking up rect properties.. here's the code

```
def moveme(self,x,y):
    if self.rect.left + x < 0:
        self.rect.left = 0
    elif self.rect.right + x > 700:
        self.rect.right = 700
    elif self.rect.top + y < 0:
        self.rect.top = 0
    elif self.rect.bottom + y > 400:
        self.rect.bottom = 400
    else:
        self.rect.move_ip((x,y))
```

where 400 is the height of your window, and 700 is the width

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it here:

```
import pygame
running = True
GREEN = (0,  255,  0)
BLACK = (0,  0,  0)
FPS = 30
pygame.init()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() #groupes all sprites
all_sprites.update()
tab.fill(BLACK) #any color
all_sprites.draw(tab)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WIDTH = 500 #YOUR WIDTH
HEIGHT = 500 #YOUR HEIGHT
tab = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)) #window width and height


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 #your Character
 def __init__():
  pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("Ship.png") #your image or shape/sprites look
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, (HEIGHT / 2)) #sprites Position
 def update(self):
   key = pygame.key.get_pressed();
   #stop at edge commands (might need to ajust)
   if(self.rect.x >= (WIDTH-200)):
      self.rect.x -= 10;
   elif(self.rect.x <= 0):
      self.rect.x += 10;
   elif(self.rect.y <= 0):
      self.rect.y += 10;
   elif(self.rect.y >= (HEIGHT-200)):
    self.rect.y -= 10
   else:
    #sprites move commands
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:self.rect.x += 10;
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:self.rect.x -= 10;
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:self.rect.y -= 10;
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:self.rect.y += 10;

player = Player() #makes the sprite that the player controlles
all_sprites.add(player)
while (running):
 clock.tick(FPS)
 for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
 all_sprites.update() #updates screen
 tab.fill(BLACK)
 all_sprites.draw(tab) #adds all sprites to the screen
 pygame.display.flip()
```

I got some of this from someone else but i can't remember but i think this will help --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 note: you might need to ajust some variables and whitespace and more. (p.s.: i'm not good at grammar) also, sorry that its long i don't think it will work without all this stuff.